# Does a positive Mantel-Haenszel chi square statistic in a trend test indicate a positive trend?

Tags: chi-squared-test, trend

When running my analysis on a dataset, I find a positive Mantel-Haenszel chi square trend statistic. Does this mean that the trend in the data is positive or simply that there is a trend? The data deals with the improvement of patients' symptoms after taking a drug or a placebo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Large values of the statistic would be associated with trend either way (to see this yourself, reverse the ordering of your categories, and see that the statistic doesn't change)

Comment: More generally, statistics with a Chi square distribution of any sort are always positive so their sign can't give any information.